# Cannot write changes to hosts file at Windows 7 by GVIM

Tags: windows-7, windows, vim, permissions, gvim

I removed read only permission from `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file and file is not hidden. I belong to Administrator group at Windows 7 system.

- When I open file in gvim without admnistrative permissions by command `:e C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`
  and then I try to make changes messeges appear:

> W10: Warning: Changes at read only file
>
> E303: Cannot open swap file for C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

after `:w!` command message appear:

> E212 Cannot open file for write

- When I open file in gvim WITH admnistrative permissions and than open file by command `e: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file saves correctly by `:w`

What should I do to save changes using Gvim while opening Gvim without administrative permissions?

Comment: It's possible, but would leave the file writable for any program, even ran without administrative permissions. And that's not secure.

Answer (score -1):

You must open a program with admin permissions to write to a file with restricted write access.  If you're going to write to a file that requires admin permissions, you must open the program with administrative permissions before you make the change.

If you have already made changes and you want to save them rather than redoing them, I suggest you save the file elsewhere and the copy the changed one over the original.